# Spring RestController requires CSRF

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, csrf

I have built a RestController, which should help manage tags in a web application. I will be calling all of the methods through AJAX (using JQuery), but Spring-Boot's default Security results in the following (when calling from Postman):

{
    "timestamp": 1438800538949,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.",
    "path": "/tag/add"
}

What is the best way to get the CSRF token to do the calls from JQuery? I assume it's better than to disable it. What about when using it from PostMan?

This is the code of the controller:

```
@RestController
public class TagController {

@Autowired
private TagService tagService;

@RequestMapping(name = "/tag/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<TagList> getTagList() {
    TagList result = new TagList(tagService.list());
    return new ResponseEntity<TagList>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(name = "/tag/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> addTag(@RequestBody AlterTagForm form) {
    try {
        tagService.addTag(form.getArticleId(), form.getTagName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(name = "/tag/remove", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> removeTag(@RequestBody AlterTagForm form) {
    try {
        tagService.removeTag(form.getArticleId(), form.getTagName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As it is Rest api, you can disable csrf check in configuration. Normally this is done by `httpSecurity.csrf().disable()` in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter .configure()` method. Also make it stateless by `httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`. As I dont have a look at Spring boot, dont know how it's done in it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to include the csrf token within your html:

`<meta name="_csrf" id="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" id="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>`

you can do it in the form too, like this:

`<input type="hidden"
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>`

but i prefer to do that in the meta, because that is in the header and i have this for every template with a form (i use thymeleaf, fragments etc.)

Second, you need to modify your ajax call:

```
var csrfToken = $('#_csrf').attr("content");
var csrfHeader = $('#_csrf_header').attr("content");
$.ajax({
    url : '/tag/remove',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({ id: id }),
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfHeader, csrfToken);
    }
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('finish');
});
```

To set the `requestHeader` is the most important of this.

PS: Sometimes it can be happen that the `csrf header` is null for this you can easily replace this:

`var csrfHeader = $('#_csrf_header').attr("content")`

with that:

`var csrfHeader = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';`

Comment: So that means I won't be able to call it webservice-wise, nor through a tool like Postman?

Comment: I'm not sure, because spring security generates the csrf token. i can not image that spring can validate the token from postman. i think you need a custome csrf implementation (a service where you validate the token from postman in spring)